# Is it possible to make these functions into one function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this program to add a special character when the assigned button for the character is pressed. The problem is, I'm going to have a lot of functions. Can I somehow just make one function that I can use for all of the buttons?

```
//These are buttons
var aa = document.querySelector('#aa')
var oo = document.querySelector('#oo')
var uu = document.querySelector('#uu')
var khii = document.querySelector('#khii')
//This is the text box
var textBox = document.querySelector('#typeIn')


//Functions to add a character into the text box
function addAa() {
   textBox.innerHTML += "ā";
}

function addOo() {
    textBox.innerHTML += "ō";
}

function addUu() {
    textBox.innerHTML += "ū";
}

function addKhii() {
    textBox.innerHTML += "χ";
}

//Telling the buttons to call on the functions when clicked
aa.onclick = addAa
oo.onclick = addOo 
uu.onclick = addUu
khii.onclick = addKhii
```

Additionally: why does this not work?

```
var aa = document.querySelector('#aa')
var textBox = document.querySelector('#text')

function addLetter(a) {
  textBox.innerHTML += a
}

aa.onclick = addLetter("ā")
```

This just adds the character once into the text box. Clicking on the button then does nothing. Why does it do that?

Comment: add onClick using addEventListener

Comment: `aa.addEventListener('click', () => addLetter("ā"))`

Comment: Assuming that `textBox` is either an `input` or `textarea` element, using `innerHTML` is wrong to begin with. The value for those gets set by assigning to the `value` property - `textBox.value += a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it with only one function. Pass the character as parameter to the function. Like that:

**version with addEventListener (prefered)**

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const textBox = document.querySelector('#typeIn');

btns.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', e => {
    textBox.innerHTML += e.target.getAttribute('data-char')
  })
});
```

```css
#typeIn {
  margin:10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  min-height:40px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button data-char="aa">aa</button>
<button data-char="X">X</button>
<button data-char="ō">ō</button>
<button data-char="ū">ū</button>
<div id="typeIn"></div>
```

Generally try to avoid onclick events and use eventListener instead.

**Version onclick Event**

```js
const textBox = document.querySelector('#typeIn');

function add(what) {
   textBox.innerHTML += what;
}
```

```css
#typeIn {
  margin:10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  min-height:40px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add('aa')">aa</button>
<button onclick="add('X')">X</button>
<button onclick="add('ō')">ō</button>
<button onclick="add('ū')">ū</button>
<div id="typeIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

1. Add (for example) data-value attributes to each of your buttons

```html
<button data-value="A">A</button>
<button data-value="B">B</button>
<button data-value="C">C</button>
```

2. Grab all these buttons, and add "click" event listeners to each, like so:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('button') // Use appropriate class name here
  .forEach(button =>
    button
     .addEventListener("click", (e) => 
        console.log(e.target.dataset.value) // Do whatever you want here
     )
  )
```

3. Modify the listener function's body as per your needs

Here's a link to a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andys_fiddle/vk8rtouc/11/) that I've created for demo.